# Unable to import custom operators from plugins folder airflow

Tags: python, plugins, airflow

I am new to airflow and trying to import custom operator from plugins folder in my dag.
Below is the file structure :

```
├── dags
│   ├── my_dag.py
├── myrequirements.txt
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_airflow_plugin.py
│   └── operators
│       ├── __int__.py
│       └── my_airflow_operator.py
```

my_dag.py

`from operators.my_airflow_operator import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator`

my_airflow_plugin.py

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from operators.my_airflow_operator import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator

class lambda_operator(LambdaOperator):
    pass
                    
class my_plugin(AirflowPlugin):
                    
    name = 'my_airflow_plugin'
    operators = [lambda_operator]
```

my_airflow_operator.py

```
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_lambda_hook import AwsLambdaHook


class AwsLambdaExecutionError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when there is an error executing the function.
    """


class AwsLambdaPayloadError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when there is an error with the Payload object in the response.
    """


class AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    Invoke AWS Lambda functions with a JSON payload.
    The check_success_function signature should be a single param which will receive a dict.
    The dict will be the "Response Structure" described in
    """
    
    def succeeded(response):
        payload = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())
        # do something with payload
    
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        function_name,
        region_name,
        payload,
        check_success_function,
        log_type="None",
        qualifier="$LATEST",
        aws_conn_id=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.function_name = function_name
        self.region_name = region_name
        self.payload = payload
        self.log_type = log_type
        self.qualifier = qualifier
        self.check_success_function = check_success_function
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id

    def get_hook(self):
        """
        Initialises an AWS Lambda hook
        :return: airflow.contrib.hooks.AwsLambdaHook
        """
        return AwsLambdaHook(
            self.function_name,
            self.region_name,
            self.log_type,
            self.qualifier,
            aws_conn_id=self.aws_conn_id,
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info("AWS Lambda: invoking %s", self.function_name)

        response = self.get_hook().invoke_lambda(self.payload)

        try:
            self._validate_lambda_api_response(response)
            self._validate_lambda_response_payload(response)
        except (AwsLambdaExecutionError, AwsLambdaPayloadError) as e:
            self.log.error(response)
            raise e

        self.log.info("AWS Lambda: %s succeeded!", self.function_name)



    def _validate_lambda_response_payload(self, response):
        """
        Call a user provided function to validate the Payload object for errors.
        :param response: HTTP Response from AWS Lambda.
        :type response: dict
        :return: None
        """
        if not self.check_success_function(response):
            raise AwsLambdaPayloadError(
                "AWS Lambda: error validating response payload!"
            )
```

But i get this error :
**No module named 'operators'**

I tried changing the import statement in my_dag.py to :

`from airflow.operators.my_airflow_plugin import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator`

I get this error
**No module named 'airflow.operators.my_airflow_plugin'**

Could someone please suggest what is not right here?( Airflow version is 1.10.12)

**init**.py files are empty

Comment: What Airflow version are you running?

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the original error. Looks like is related to the second line of the `my_airflow_plugin.py` . Also include the content of `plugins/ __init__.py`

Comment: AIrflow version is 1.10.12. And plugins/ __init__.py is empty. Error is this only. No module named 'operators'

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the plugin for? Is it just to expose your custom operators in the DAGs? That's not really [the purpose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html#what-for) for plugins within the Airflow architecture, starting from the version 2 this is not longer supported.

Instead of using a plugin you can create a module with your operator and use that module to import it in the DAG. You can follow [this instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html) to do that.

Comment: Hi! Thanks.Yes, i was using plugins to expose custom operator in my DAG. Now I moved my_airflow_operator.py(custom operator) from plugins to dags/ and changed the import statement in my DAG to 
from my_airflow_operator import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My airflow version is 1.10.12 but still accessing custom operators from plugins folder was showing "No module found error". Finally it worked when i moved the custom operator file to dags folder.

Comment: I have the same problems. Could you show me your structure in the DAGs folder and how you connect these plugins to DAG? Thnx!